# Determine correct tolerance/epsilon for line simplification in different zoom-levels when generating vector tiles

Tags: postgis, osm2pgsql, vector-tiles

I am writing my own vector-tile generator for a map renderer that I have written, but I am unsure of how to pick the correct epsilon value to use in the PostGIS method `ST_Simplify` depending on the zoom levels.
I'm using the web Mercator projection, and my tiles widths/heights halve on each zoom level.

Is there a suggested way to pick this epsilon value dependent on the zoom level? Because, ideally, at the highest zoom level, the epsilon value should be 0 such that there's little to no simplification of the lines. I did have some idea relating to getting the horizontal distance covered by a given tile at a particular zoom level, given by the formula:

```
distance = equatorialCircumference * cos(latitude)/2^zoomLevel
```

However I feel this is slightly unfounded, any suggestions?

Comment: `ST_Simplify` is documented as using the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm. It's not well-suited to Web Mercator, since distance is so useless in that projection, such that features in Africa will be obliterated when using a value which will barely generate any change along the coast of Russia.

Comment: @Vince then what would you suggest as an alternative method of simplifying lines for different zoom levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid noticeable visible changes, the tolerance you give to [ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology.html) should be smaller than one pixel. (Vector tiles do not have pixels, but you could assume that the tile would be displayed in the same size as a 512×512 bitmap tile on the screen.)

Please note that the default extent of a tile in the MVT format is 4096 units, so for that, it does not really make sense to use a tolerance that is smaller than 1/4096th of the tile size.

<sup>And you could simply use [ST_AsMVTGeom()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVTGeom.html)/[ST_AsMVT()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVT.html).</sup>